# What is the meaning of かつ here?

Tags: words

Hello I am wondering about かつ. I got this sentence below. For context I put the line before the one I am asking about.

でも 金で解決できるならそうすべきだ｡

何より その道のプロに任せた方が美しいし合理的**かつ**経済も回る｡

Does かつ mean "and" here perhaps? As for the rest of the sentence it's kind of difficult to translate as well, I might be completely off. But maybe along the lines of: More importantly, relying on the professionals of their line of business make the beautiful rationality and economy go around.

edit: I somehow missed the し, after 美しい. That is why I was confused when translating even more..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> 「何{なに}より その道{みち}のプロに任{まか}せた方{ほう}が美{うつく}しいし合理的{ごうりてき}**かつ**経済{けいざい}も回{まわ}る｡」

「かつ/且{か}つ」 = "moreover", "as well as", "besides", "and", etc.  This word is very often written in kana.

Your TL:

> "More importantly, relying on the professionals of their line of business make the **beautiful rationality** and economy go around."

That is a nice try, but the original surely does **not** say "beautiful rationality".  The 「し」 in 「美しい**し**」 is a conjunctive.

My TL:

> "More importantly, leaving it to the pros in the field would make it prettier, and it will be more rational; moreover, it will help the economy go around as well."

Note: I used "prettier" not knowing what kind of work/job/task it is talking about.  You have the whole context, so feel free to change that part to fit it.

Comment: Hey I totally missed the し there, my bad! That totally changes things indeed, I thought it was weird. Thank you so much for answering my question about the meaning of かつ.